# How I can select the faces that are enclosed inside the volume of another object?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this two objects, the left one is the main one, and the right one is the volume I want to use to intersect the faces I want to extrude.

[image]

To do that I'm using a geometry node like this to place the object where I need to select the faces

[image]

Now I'm trying to use the "Intersecting Edges" field of the boolean node as a selection for the extrude node, but it seems to not work

[image]

What it will be the proper way of doing this?

[image]